# What is the difference between locale and Encoding ( Terminal )

Tags: c++, c, encoding, character-encoding, locale

I have tried a few ways to set the terminal 'encoding' from a c++ program.
All I could do is to change the locale. or the LANG variable.

Still I am able to enter characters which are of different encoding than the LANG ( and output of nl_langinfo(CODESET) )

But , if I go to Terminal > Set Character Encoding > ISO-8859-15 ( or something ) then it is allowing only ISO-8859-15 .
Can I achive the same thing ( setting from GUI ) from my C++ program as well ?

I used setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"") to set the encoding to the terminal encoding , but it just uses the LANG variable.And allows other characters too.

( After Terminal > Set Character Encoding > ISO-8859-1 ( Latin1 ) )

```
>setenv LANG en_US.iso885915 --> latin9
>./a.out 
Current Locale : C
Lang info : ANSI_X3.4-1968
Trying to change locale from C to ""
Current Locale : en_US.iso885915 
Lang info : ISO-8859-15
Enter some string :¤¦¨´¸¼½¾ dfsafas  --> but these are Latin1 charaters !!
Entered string : ¤¦¨´¸¼½¾ dfsafas --> They are even printed back !!
```

So , this brought me down to the question if my understanding about the locale and encoding are correct or not.

Can someone please clarify the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encoding is only a part of locale settings and for terminals it affects how terminal displays and process input.

Terminal encoding and locale setting for a program running withing terminal pretty much independent and might not match or can be misconfigured.

setlocale() will set or query the program's current locale.

Terminals usually spawns a new shell and setting LANG or LC_* environment variables will affect only programs that will run withing this shell.

Also setting locale or encoding does not prevent "other" characters to be entered.

This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48689/effect-of-lang-on-terminal) should help to clarify things.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination , that clears many things.The reference was also helpful.