# gcc ncurses printing extend characters (glyphs) such as char 223

Tags: gcc, ncurses, extended-ascii

I am writing a terminal program for the Raspberry Pi using ncurses. I want to add a shadow around a box. I want to use `mvaddch()` to print extended characters such as char 233 (upper half box character). What would be the syntax for the `mvaddch()` command? Or is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably referring to something like [code page 866](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195074.aspx).  ncurses will assume your terminal shows characters consistent with the [*locale encoding*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16544456/what-is-the-difference-between-locale-and-encoding-terminal), which probably is UTF-8.  So (unless you want to convert the characters in your program) the way to go is using Unicode values.

The Unicode organization has tables which you can use to lookup a particular code, e.g., ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/PC/CP866.TXT.  For your example, the relevant row is

```
0xdf   0x2580   #UPPER HALF BLOCK
```

(because 0xdf is 223).  You would use the Unicode `0x2580` in a call to the function [mvaddwstr](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addwstr.3x.html), e.g.

```
wchar_t mydata[] = { 0x2580, 0 };
mvaddwstr(0,0, mydata);
```

(the similarly-named [`wadd_wch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_add_wch.3x.html#h3-add_wch) uses a data structure which is more complicated).

You would have to link with the **ncursesw** library, and of course [initialize your program's locale using `setlocale`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Initialization) as mentioned in the ncurses manual page.